# Positioning of text in tikzfadingfrompicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, xetex, fontspec, transparency

I'm trying to create an effect in LaTeX Beamer where an image is cut out in the shape of a letter. I want the letter to be placed in the top left corner of the frame, and in the background, so text can be placed in front of it.

[image: desired result]

However, I can't seem to get the positioning right.

A minimal .tex file with the problem follows:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}    \usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\imgletter}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=letter#2]
    \node[text=transparent!0]{\fontspec[Scale=26]{Code Pro Black}#2};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,anchor=north west]
  \node[scope fading=letter#2,fit fading=false]
  at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\title{Presentation title.}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{Bert {Van Vreckem}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  % Only bottom right of the letter is shown
  \imgletter{blurred-background-cellphone-coffee-842554.jpg}{H}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  % Only right part of the letter is visible
  \imgletter{blurred-background-cellphone-coffee-842554.jpg}{M}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  % same as previous page, letter is placed slightly higher
  \imgletter{blurred-background-cellphone-coffee-842554.jpg}{M}
  {\huge \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  % Left and top part of the letter are clipped
  \imgletter{blurred-background-cellphone-coffee-842554.jpg}{M}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The image is positioned the way I wanted, but the shape of the letter is all over the place. Why is the position of the letter influenced by other text on the frame? I used the `remember picture,overlay` option to avoid that.

[image: compilation result]

What am I missing?

I use an .otf font, so XeTeX is used for compiling the .tex file.

External files needed to reproduce this:

- [Code Pro Black font](https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-code-pro-black-f62435.htm)
- [The stock photo](https://www.pexels.com/photo/man-with-hand-on-temple-looking-at-laptop-842554/)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! My guess is that using `\frame[t]` will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, it's worse now: I only see the bottom right of the letter shapes now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @marmots nice answer, in which he already solved all the problems by adding the bounding box etc., so please accept his answer.

The only difference in this answer is that it moves the letter to the background of the frame which has 2 tiny advantages:

- it will make the position independent from the frame content, i.e. it works for all alignments, not only top aligned frames, frames with and without frametitle, plain frames ...
- The command only has to be used when the letter changes, not necessarily on every frame

---

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}    \usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defbeamertemplate{background}{imgletter}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[scope fading=letter#2,fit fading=false,
  anchor=north west]
  at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\foreach \X in {H,M}
{\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=letter\X]
    \path[use as bounding box] (-14,-4) rectangle (6,12); 
    \node[text=transparent!0,scale=26](X) at (0,0) {\X}; %\fontspec[Scale=26]{Code Pro Black}
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
}

\title{Presentation title.}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{Bert {Van Vreckem}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{background}[imgletter]{example-image}{H}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background}[imgletter]{example-image}{M}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \huge \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sam! I noticed as well that text on the slides still had impact on the position of the letter shape. Your solution is exactly what I need. Now the only thing missing are some ducks... :-D

Comment: @BertVanVreckem You can replace your stock image with `example-image-duck` :)

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I did not download the fonts you are using since I do not have any knowledge on the installation of those.

However, the issue does not seem to depend on the font. Why does the stuff get shifted around despite the absolute positioning? I don't really know. In what follows, I'll present a way to place the stuff wherever you want. The ingredients of the workaround are:

1. Do the `tikzfadingfrompicture` beforehand.
2. Use `\frame[t]` instead of `\frame`.
3. Use a bounding box path in `tikzfadingfrompicture` to shift the letter. If you choose the bounding box differently, you will be able to avoid that the letter gets cut. I am just using this here to show what you could do with it.

Here come code and output.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\imgletter}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[scope fading=letter#2,fit fading=false,
  anchor=north west]
  at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\title{Presentation title.}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{Bert {Van Vreckem}}
\date{\today}

\foreach \X in {H,M}
{\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=letter\X]
    \path[use as bounding box] (-12,0) rectangle (6,8); 
    \node[text=transparent!0,scale=26](X) at (0,0) {\X}; %\fontspec[Scale=26]{Code Pro Black}
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  % Only bottom right of the letter is shown
  \imgletter{blurred-background-cellphone-coffee-842554.jpg}{H}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
  % Only right part of the letter is visible
  \imgletter{blurred-background-cellphone-coffee-842554.jpg}{M}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
  % same as previous page, letter is placed slightly higher
  \imgletter{blurred-background-cellphone-coffee-842554.jpg}{M}
  {\huge \textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
  % Left and top part of the letter are clipped
  \imgletter{blurred-background-cellphone-coffee-842554.jpg}{M}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to look in to this! Indeed, the font is irrelevant to the issue. I'm going to play around with your code a bit...

Comment: @BertVanVreckem You're welcome. I just found that there seem to be even deeper issues. The results in the pdf and the animated gif do not match. In particular, the letters are not cut when I look at the pdf with `preview`, however they are in the animated gif. That is, there are in addition some viewer issues, something that you may want to check before uploading your talk on another machine... ;-)

Comment: Due to fontsize changes within the same paragraph the M on the 3rd frame has a slightly different vertical position. If you would add a `\par` after `\end{tikzpicture}` this could be avoided.

Comment: @BertVanVreckem I think that you should accept samcarters great answer, the more so since you are using it. Other users may also find her answer more useful, I am one of these others. ;-)